# Ruby Exceptions -- Why "else"?

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm trying to understand exceptions in Ruby but I'm a little confused.  The tutorial I'm using says that if an exception occurs that does not match any of the exceptions identified by the rescue statements, you can use an "else" to catch it:

```
begin  
# -  
rescue OneTypeOfException  
# -  
rescue AnotherTypeOfException  
# -  
else  
# Other exceptions
ensure
# Always will be executed
end
```

However, I also saw later in the tutorial "rescue" being used without an exception specified:

```
begin
    file = open("/unexistant_file")
    if file
         puts "File opened successfully"
    end
rescue
    file = STDIN
end
print file, "==", STDIN, "\n"
```

If you can do this, then do I ever *need* to use else?  Or can I just use a generic rescue at the end like this?

```
begin  
# -  
rescue OneTypeOfException  
# -  
rescue AnotherTypeOfException  
# -  
rescue
# Other exceptions
ensure
# Always will be executed
end
```

Comment: What's the tutorial, so I know not to recommend it?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm After some Googling, I think the tutorial the asker was following was http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_exceptions.htm. Bonus WTF: the author of that tutorial seems to have plagiarised the first example from http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html (where it was already incorrect), but made it worse still by screwing up the indentation of the comments. And yes, I think it'd be wise to steer people away from it - what a great combination of incompetence *and* dishonesty on display!

Comment: Just in the case somebody encounters this same issue. In "The Ruby Way. Third Edition"  the authors state that an `else` clause inside a `begin` block is used to rescue errors of a type not specified in the preceeding `rescue` clauses (Basically the same that the tutorial from this question said). That is incorrect. It confused me for a while

Comment: To be clear: In a `begin/end` block, the `else` block is only run when there are NO exceptions raised. It is NOT a catch-all for "any other" exception. The need for `else` is pretty rare...typically you'd just put your ongoing, non-exception, code in the main `begin` block, before any rescues. See later answers for some legit esoteric uses of `else`.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `else` is for when the block completes without an exception thrown. The `ensure` is run whether the block completes successfully or not. Example:

```
begin
  puts "Hello, world!"
rescue
  puts "rescue"
else
  puts "else"
ensure
  puts "ensure"
end
```

This will print `Hello, world!`, then `else`, then `ensure`.

Comment: Why include the else portion in the begin block?

Comment: @AntarrByrd In Ruby, `begin` is like `try` in other languages. The `else`, here, means, do this if no exceptions have been thrown in that `begin` (`try`) block.

Comment: But if the code in the begin block does not throw an error. You can continue there since thats the only case in which it will run.

Comment: @AntarrByrd With one difference: the exception handlers will be disabled in the `else` (while still being run before the `ensure`).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a concrete use-case for `else` in a `begin` expression. Suppose you're writing automated tests, and you want to write a method that returns the error raised by a block. But you also want the test to fail if the block doesn't raise an error. You can do this:

```
def get_error_from(&block)
  begin
    block.call
  rescue => err
    err  # we want to return this
  else
    raise "No error was raised"
  end
end
```

Note that you can't move the `raise` inside the `begin` block, because it'll get `rescue`d. Of course, there are other ways without using `else`, like checking whether `err` is `nil` after the `end`, but that's not as succinct.

Personally, I rarely use `else` in this way because I think it's rarely needed, but it does come in handy in those rare cases.

**EDIT**

Another use case occurred to me. Here's a typical `begin`/`rescue`:

```
begin
  do_something_that_may_raise_argument_error
  do_something_else_when_the_previous_line_doesnt_raise
rescue ArgumentError => e
  handle_the_error
end
```

Why is this less than ideal? Because the intent is to `rescue` when `do_something_that_may_raise_argument_error` raises `ArgumentError`, *not* when `do_something_else_when_the_previous_line_doesnt_raise` raises.

It's usually better to use `begin`/`rescue` to wrap the minimum code you want to protect from a `raise`, because otherwise:

- you may mask bugs in the code that wasn't supposed to `raise`
- the intention of `rescue` is harder to decipher. Someone (including your future self) may read the code and wonder "Which expression did I want to protect? It *looks* like expression ABC... but maybe expression DEF too???? What was the author intending?!" Refactoring becomes much more difficult.

You avoid those problems with this simple change:

```
begin
  do_something_that_may_raise_argument_error
rescue ArgumentError => e
  handle_the_error
else
  do_something_else_when_the_previous_line_doesnt_raise
end
```

Comment: Why couldn't you just `raise "No error was raised"` after the `begin rescue end` block? Wouldn't that be exactly the same as doing it inside that `else`?

Comment: @Magne The only way that would work is if you *also* use an early `return`, i.e. `return err` instead of just `err`. If you don't, the method can't return the block's error because you have an unconditional raise at the end of the method. I usually try to avoid early/explicit `return`s (except in guard-clause-style) because it's easier to follow; which is why the `else` syntax is more appealing.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice that the `begin rescue end` was inside a method where you want to return the error. But, consider my question if you don't need to return the error (ie. a standalone `begin rescue end`).

Comment: I guess it would only be the same if you do something to halt execution from within the rescue block (like re-raising the error). In that case the else would be superflous.

Answer (score 1):

The `else` block in a begin rescue end block is used when you are perhaps expecting an exception of some sort to occur. If you run through all of your expected exceptions but still have nothing raised, then in your else block you can do whatever's needed now that you know that your original code ran error free.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see for the `else` block is if you want to execute something before the `ensure` block when the code in the `begin` block didn't raise any errors.

```
begin
  puts "Hello"
rescue
  puts "Error"
else
  puts "Success"
ensure
  puts "my old friend"
  puts "I've come to talk with you again."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `else` you sometimes can merge two nested `begin end` blocks.
So (simplified example from my current code) instead of:

```
  begin
    html = begin
      NetHTTPUtils.request_data url
    rescue NetHTTPUtils::Error => e
      raise unless 503 == e.code
      sleep 60
      retry
    end
    redo unless html["market"]
  end
```

you write:

```
  begin
    html = NetHTTPUtils.request_data url
  rescue NetHTTPUtils::Error => e
    raise unless 503 == e.code
    sleep 60
    retry
  else
    redo unless html["market"]
  end
```