# ruby does not look beyond the first rescue code?

Tags: ruby, exception, selenium, watir-webdriver, rescue

From my understanding of the docs this general [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279956/ruby-exceptions-why-else) should work:

```
begin
 try1
rescue
 try2
rescue
 try3
.
.
.
rescue
 puts "Everybody failed, sorry man!"
end
```

However whenever I try to open up a Watir-Webdriver browser, it never seems to try beyond the second **$browser = Watir::Browser.new**, ending the script in line 189 with     *Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)*

**Code.rb:**

```
begin
 $browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => "botmode") # **line 186**

rescue
 $browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox)   # **line 189**

rescue  # local selenium htmlunit
  puts __LINE__.to_s + ": #{$!}"    
#  $browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :htmlunit)  # but needs Javascript for AJAX support...
  $browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true, :cssSelectorsEnabled=>true, :nativeEvents=>false) ) 

rescue # Try to use VentanaPC if still failing..  
 $browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://5.19.111.226:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox)  

rescue  # no browser left to failover to
  puts __LINE__.to_s + ": #{$@.to_s}"
end

# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

To make line 186 fail, I deliberately set DISPLAY=:88 in advance to a non-existent Xserver, so this error is okay: *186: unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)*

Where am I going wrong here, or is there a better way to do this? Is this something particular to Selenium or Watir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong, this does not work as you expect:

```
irb(main):062:0> begin
irb(main):063:1*   raise StandardError
irb(main):064:1> rescue
irb(main):065:1>   puts "test1"
irb(main):066:1>   raise StandardError
irb(main):067:1> rescue
irb(main):068:1>   puts "test2"
irb(main):069:1> end
test1
StandardError: StandardError
    from (irb):66:in `rescue in irb_binding'
    from (irb):62
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

`test2` is not printed. Multiple `rescue`s are for different exception types, you can't catch errors in other `rescue` blocks like that. You *could* instead use nested `begin/rescue` blocks, but this case seems complex enough to use a more general approach:

```
methods = [
  lambda { Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => "botmode") },
  lambda { Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox) },
  lambda { Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true, :cssSelectorsEnabled=>true, :nativeEvents=>false) ) },
  lambda { Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://5.19.111.226:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox) },
]

def get_first_successful(methods)
  methods.each do |m|
    begin
      return m.call
    rescue
    end
  end
  nil
end

$browser = get_first_successful(methods)
```

This will select the first method which doesn't fail. However, I don't see how the last one could be successful if the second one failed, you might rethink your options here.

Comment: Thank you! I use this retry-failover extensively in my scripts and usually the code blocks are several lines long. Added `get_first_successful` to my personal lib. The last/4th method here uses a different host which I confirmed works in `irb`

Answer (score 0):

The first `rescue` will catch any `StandardError`. So will the others, but since those errors are already caught by the first `rescue`, they will never have chance to actually encounter any `StandardError`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple rescues are for rescuing from different exception types; what you have is a single block with a bunch of unqualified rescues, so only one will trigger. You want *nested* begin/rescue/ends, or a different approach altogether.

Comment: I have written nested, and it works, but got really messy real fast, when all I needed was to keep trying code blocks until one worked. I don't know of different approaches that are lean--unless there is a way to reset exception type handling after every `rescue`?

Comment: @Marcos See Niklas' answer, although I might just keep the parameters in a map or something rather than using lambdas--doesn't matter a whole lot.